# How do I exclude specific URLs from authenticating using Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Assuming I have a web app residing in Azure and using Azure AD, and I configured it to authenticate using Azure AD
settings -> Authentication / Authorization -> Authentication Providers -> Azure Active Directory

Now I want certain pages and URL paths to be publicly available (without need for authentication).

How do I configure that?

Comment: thats up to your web app. what are you using?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't really used the "Easy Auth" on my Web Apps. I don't know if you can ignore certain routes in that. A sure way would be to disable the Authentication/Authorization ("Easy Auth") and instead configure authentication/authorization within your app.

Comment: Daniel A. White - I am researching this area. We have several apps and we want to use azure ad SSO for them. One is an ASP.NET mixed with angular pages and some public pages, one is an angular web app and more like these.
We thought we could use the "easy auth" of azure since it's easy to implement. I've been told by someone that it's absolutely possible to have public pages (he's not available for further questioning right now) in this scenario. So this is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I stumbled upon the answer.

The way to configure that is described in the following article:

[Expanding App Service Authentication/Authorization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/)

You need to leave the "action to take" drop-down as "Allow request (no action)" and then the application may redirect the user to the log-in page as needed. This was not sufficiently explained in the Azure portal and led to some confusion on my part.

Comment: In my Wep API app on azure, can I leave one endpoint open without authentication ? have to done something like this, because following the link you have provided I am not able to get the solution